# Displaying an image in a div where the image is a filename

Tags: javascript, html, json

Please explain where i am going wrong

I am evaluating a **xmlhttp.responceText**

```
var list = eval ('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
```

The response from this contains **JSON encoded data...**

I can display the data by doing...

```
document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML=list[0].picture;

<div id="list0.picture"></div>
```

The responce is a filename that changes when new data is sent..

i.e. **picture001.jpg**

How can i turn this filename into a visual image on screen instead of the file name

I have tried variations of below but i cant get it to work.. im sure it is simple but it has me stumped...

```
document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/('list[0].picture')" />';
```

**my pictures are stored in /testsite/covers**

Comment: JSON data can be manipulated as a Javascript object (hence Javascript-Object-Notation). You shouldn't have to do an eval on it if it's actually JSON data.

Comment: hi @Organiccat the data is JSON encoded in a PHP file and then i use the GET command in JavaScript to get the PHP output.. I though i had to do a "var list = eval ('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');" to return the data as a variable called LIST, is there a better way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `+` when performing string concatenation

```
document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML=
         '<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '" />';
```

On side note, You don't need to use `eval()`.

Comment: I`m not sure about this parentheses, why them?

Comment: @scel.pi, Even I am not sure about parentheses, but OP will have  a fair idea where is propblem

Comment: "directly" as in `json.parse()`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var someFileName = 'http://communio.stblogs.org/Donkey.jpg';

// create an element
var img = document.createElement('img');

// set its attributes
img.setAttribute('src', someFileName);

// attach the image to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Thats the most ellegant way to do this! UP!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '" />';`